# SQL: Parameters from excel generate error: String data, right truncation

Tags: sql, parameters, excel-2010, truncation

After adding parameter2 to the query, I got an error message: SQL Server Error “String Data, Right Truncation”.

The parameters are entered by the user in Excel 2010 spreadsheet and used in the SQL statement to update the Report.

Example:

Fiscal year (parameter1): 2014, 
GL Date (parameter2) yyyymmdd:     20140228

The error is generated by: "GLPOST.JRNLDATE<=?" which is parameter2

```
WHERE GLAMF.ACCTID = GLPOST.ACCTID AND GLACGRP.ACCTGRPCOD = GLAMF.ACCTGRPCOD AND 
GLPOST.DRILLDWNLK = BKTRAND.DDLINK AND GLACGRP.SORTCODE='1000' AND   
GLPOST.FISCALYR>=? AND GLPOST.JRNLDATE<=?
```

In the database, GLPOST.FISCALYR is (char(4), not null) and works fine.
GLPOST.JRNLDATE is (decimal(9,0), not null) causes an error.  If I enter a hardcoded value such as: 20140228, 20131231, etc... it works but it doesn't seem to pick up the value from the cell.

I did try different formattings but with no success, any idea? thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try casting the parameter like this:

GLPOST.FISCALYR>=? AND GLPOST.JRNLDATE<=cast(? as decimal(9,0))

Comment: I did try casting but it didn't work, however if I remove the parameter1 (Fiscal year) the query runs well. Maybe the value intended for parameter2 (char(4)) was pushed into parameter1...

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to add the parameters?

Comment: The code is exactly as I posted above, it's an ODBC connection, the code is in the: "Command text" and then each "?" is associated with a cell in the Excel spreadsheet. I'm guessing the issue is somewhere there